# Spring security oauth2 with 2 applications (same client ID and client secret)

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, cors, spring-security-oauth2

I created an IT-solution consisting of:

- an Angular frontend that includes 2 client-applications
- 2 APIs, based on Java
- a third-party authorization server (single sign-on)

I use Spring security oauth2 (OIDC) library for authentication. The 2 Angular clients consume both APIs and use the same client ID and secret. If a user is logged in to the first client application, they should **not** be prompted to log in again to the second client application.

Basically this works fine, but even though the user is already logged in, the second client application also tries to connect to the authorization endpoint. In addition, a CORS exception is thrown when the second client attempts to access the authorization endpoint.

I think the second client should be able to fetch the user-info without going through the authorization/token endpoint again. Is the above mentioned approach correct? And: How am I supposed to handle this situation with Spring Security Oauth2 library (involving 2 or more client backend java applications with same client id and secret)? How do I get the user-info from the second client application?

When I try the above, the second API call results in the following error (the first API call is successful after successful login):

```
Retrieving domain category:
:8082/review-web/app/home:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://gateway.cert.auth.com/affweb/CAS/oidc/EXTERNAL_v0/**authorize?**response_type=code&client_id=596346&scope=openid%20profile%20credential_data%20email&state=wmy3woFyTjrbhyE2aHXLrpFSEnbXnUG4rcx4pdcSZso%3D&redirect_uri=https://dev.local.com:8083/core-api/app/login/oauth2/code/core-api-client&nonce=ridDePx0JMeSv4qJkvv74xkV5ev-lvVMb7inhG8wzBs' (redirected from 'https://dev.local.com:8083/core-api/app/api/all/category') from origin 'https://dev.local.com:8082' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 1):

OAuth2 wording:

- **authorization-server** (not authentication) authenticates users and certifies identities (emits access, ID and refresh tokens)
- **client** is the one consuming REST resources (Angular app in your case)
- **resource-server** serves resources (Spring apps with `@RestController`)

My 2 cent guess is you configured spring apps with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` for OAuth2 login. If so, this is wrong. You should instead:

- authenticate users from your Angular app and send authorized requests (set `Authorization` header with a valid access-token). For that, use an OIDC client lib. My favorite for Angular is [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client).
- use `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` (not `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`) to secure REST API end-points. Refer to [this tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) if you don't know how to.

Last, you should use a "public" client when authenticating users from a rich client (no client secret as such clients can't get a secret actually secret). The flow to use should be authorization-code **with PKCE**.

Comment: ch4mp -  you are right. I meant authorization (Not authentication) server and I use spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client.  Let me go thru the links you sent. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ch4mp - Some questions 1) Is there any specific reason to choose angular-auth-oidc-client (over angular-oauth2-oidc).  2) In what situations, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client can be used ? 3) Do you have any examples for multiple resource servers (i.e. multiple backend APIs) and one authentication server. In this situation, I think we could use either one access token for all resource servers or multiple access tokens (i.e. one access token for each resource server).

Comment: angular-auth-oidc-client is capable of multi-tenancy: it can keep several authentication context at the same time (send requests to URI_A with an access token from an authorization-server and requests to URI_B with an access-token from another authorization-server). Aso it is widely used, even if not as much as Angular-Oauth2-oidc, and maintainers seem more concerned when I faced a blocker issue.

Comment: If all the resource-servers accept identities from your authorization server, yes, use a single access-token. Just configure your client lib to position authorization header with access token (angular-auth-oidc-client provides with an HTTP interceptor for that). But if your clients issue requests to other domains (call Facebook or Google APIs for instance), then you'll have to authorize requests with different access-token. This where the multi configuration context feature jumps in.

Comment: Thanks. I believe the latest version (angular-auth-oidc-client 15.0.2) will work with Angular 9.x version ?